# C# dictionary<> missing key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, delegates, keynotfoundexception

When i do val = dict["nonexistent key"] i get System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
Is there a way i have my dictionary call a member function with the key as a param to generate a value?

-edit-
Maybe i should of been more specific. I want to AUTOMATICALLY call a member function to do what it needs create the proper value for that key. In this case it makes an entry in my DB then gives me back its unique handle. I'll post below what my solution was.

Comment: I think my solution does the exact same thing. What else do you need? What exactly do you mean from _automatically_. You should somehow specify which method to call (or you can hardcode the method in my solution instead of passing it and make it pretty automatic). Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: Mehrdad: When i was posting this i was hoping i could do what my code does (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718610/c-dictionary-missing-key/720794#720794) w/o writing an implementation (since the standard is likely to be better). I didnt like these solutions below bc i use dict[key] in many

Comment: places. So i would have to copy/paste it everywhere which i hate to do or call a function instead which i also dislike so i decide to emulate the lookup so i can use object naturally. i didnt know i using this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718610/c-dictionary-missing-key/720827#720827

Comment: Ah-ha. Got it. Yes, that's the way you should be going.

Answer (score 20):

Use an extension method:

```
static class DictionaryExtensions {
   public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dic, TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueGenerator) {
      TValue val;
      if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out val))
         return val;
      return valueGenerator(key);
   }
}
```

You can call it with:

```
dic.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistent key", key => "null");
```

Or pass a member function:

```
dic.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistent key", MyMemberFunction);
```

Comment: You could even have an overload that returned a 'default' T ;).

Comment: This is a nice use of extension methods... I've often done similar things when using lists/collections/enumerations (LINQ to XML in particular).

Answer (score 15):

```
Object value;
if(dict.TryGetValue("nonexistent key", out value))
{
    // this only works when key is found..
}
// no exception is thrown here..
```

Comment: ive never seen "out" used before what does that do?

Comment: @Crash893: It's used to declare output parameters and to pass arguments to those parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.80).aspx

Comment: out is to pass parameter as a reference, but difference between out and ref is, you do not have to initialize a variable in order to pass it as out, but if you need to pass variable as ref, you have to initialize it.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an aside, the technique you're talking about is called [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Answer (score 1):

TryGetValue() is good. You can also use ContainsKey() if you aren't performance constrained or don't need the value.

Comment: Why would performance be an issue? ContainsKey is an O(1) operation.

Comment: If you need to return the value then you need to retrieve it from the Dictionary as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey("TestKey") 
{       
  System.Print(myDictionary["TestKey"]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string Q = "nonexistent key";
    string A = "";


    if(dict.containskey(Q))
    {
        A= dict[Q];
    }
    else
    {
       //handler code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyDictionary<K, V>
{
    Dictionary<K, V> o = new Dictionary<K, V>();
    public delegate V NonExistentKey(K k);
    NonExistentKey nonExistentKey;
    public MyDictionary(NonExistentKey nonExistentKey_)
    {   o = new Dictionary<K, V>();
        nonExistentKey = nonExistentKey_;
    }

    public V this[K k]
    {
        get {
            V v;
            if (!o.TryGetValue(k, out v))
            {
                v = nonExistentKey(k);
                o[k] = v;
            }
            return v;
        }
        set {o[k] = value;}
    }
```

}